# Random Number have a value less than the desired value

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I am creating a random number generator and when I run the program, the displayed number can be less than the desired value.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Random _rand = new Random();

        private void RandomNumberGenerator()
        {
            int random = _rand.Next(1, 10000);
            string text;

            text = "TP0" + random.ToString();
            label1.Text = text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RandomNumberGenerator();
        }
```

Every time I click the button, it will generate a new random number, but sometimes the number can be less than `10000`. Example: I got `TP08212`, but the next time I generated a new value, I got `TP0724`. How does that happen?

And how do I prevent a number that was already displayed from being displayed again?

Comment: Change to `_rand.Next(1000, 10000);` if you want min to be 1000 and max to be 10000

Comment: `but sometimes the number can be less than 10000` . It will always be less than 10000. What is strange?

Comment: If you want a fixed width of 5 digits use `random.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')`

Answer (score 1):

Read the documention: [Random.Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The min value you provided is 1.. 724 is greater than 1. everything ok

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
minValue
Type: System.Int32
The inclusive lower bound of the random number returned.

maxValue
Type: System.Int32
The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned. 
maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

Return Value
Type: System.Int32
32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; 
that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue. 
If minValue equals maxValue, minValue is returned.
```

calling the two argument version of `Next` will always generate a number within the range [minValue, maxValue)

Answer (score 0):

If you want five digits, and the second is always one or more, get a random number in the range 1000..9999:

```
int random = _rand.Next(1000, 10000);
```

If you want five digits, but still a range from one and up, format the random number to four digits:

```
text = "TP0" + random.ToString("0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

The range you set is 1-10000. What's wrong? If you want values more than 10000:
random+=10000 that will make the range 10001-20000.

All value of random add it on a array at every new generate no. check that array.